# How can I set ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true" in background .cs files

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's my XAML Code:

```
<t:HeadingViewBase
    xmlns ="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:M.Templates"
    x:Name="ContentPage"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
    ios:Page.PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden="true"
```

Does anyone know how I can set the UseSafeArea to be true in the background CS ?

Here is what I tried:

```
    public HeadingView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.Page.UsingSafeArea = true;
        Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.Page.PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden = true;
    }
```

However it gives me error messages saying:

> /Users/r/Projects/M1/M/Templates/Pages/HeadingView.xaml.cs(13,13):
> Error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'UsingSafeArea' because it is a 'method
> group' (CS1656)
>
> /Users/r/Projects/M1/M/Templates/Pages/HeadingView.xaml.cs(13,13):
> Error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden'
> because it is a 'method group' (CS1656)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platform specifics are defined as extensions via a (static) `BindableProperty` so it is usable via XAML, along a static GetXXXX and SetXXXX extension for code usage.

So, [`UseSafeArea`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/f35ae07a0a8471d255f7a1ebdd51499e10e0a4cb/Xamarin.Forms.Core/PlatformConfiguration/iOSSpecific/Page.cs#L61) is defined as a `Page` class extension, thus

```
yourPageInstance.On<iOS>.SetUseSafeArea(true);
var safeAreaValue = yourPageInstance.On<iOS>.GetUseSafeArea();
```

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/#consuming-the-platform-specific